# My method on factorials of decimal digits?

Tags: factorial

I've been looking around at decimal factorials for a while, and have seen several methods. However, the following is how I thought one obtained decimal factorials:

Take a fractional number, say $5.67$, and separate it into the following: $5!$ which is as you'd expect, then divide each decimal digit following the decimal point into individual decimals plus $1$, so it becomes $5! \cdot 1.6 \cdot 1.07$. Multiply these together and the result is $205.44$, thus based on my method of factorial of fractional numbers, $5.67! = 205.44$. First of all, I would like to know how accurate or inaccurate my method is, and second of all, has **anyone else** tried this before? If you have, please describe your findings, if allowed.

*Edit*: Also, I assume that this formula may be highly inaccurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting/collating comments:

You may of course define anything you like.  Whether it should have the same name as something else common in the literature and whether or not it is useful is an entirely different story.

If we were to want to extend the factorial function, there are a few properties we would surely want.  First, that the values agree for each natural number.  Your extension does accomplish this.  Second, that we would have $x! = x\times (x-1)!$.  Again, your extension does accomplish this, so good job on that (*assuming you take care to be referring to the decimal expansion of $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ to avoid issues when moving to negative numbers*).

Additional properties that we would likely want would be for it to be increasing over the reals $[1,\infty)$ and continuous.  Your extension fails to be here noting that $(1.99)! = 1!\times 1.9\times 1.09 = 2.071>2!$ and further that $\lim\limits_{x\to 2} x!$ doesn't exist since from the right it would be $2.00000\dots$ which would equal $2$ but from the left it would be $1.99999\dots$ which would be $\prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty (1+9\times 10^{-k})\approx 2.0917288\dots$

The most common extension to the factorial function would be the [Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) (*with an offset*).  This function has the desired properties plus many more.  It extends the factorial to the entire complex plane (*except non-positive integers which are poles*), it is analytic, meromorphic, holomorphic, and has other nice properties.  Of course, many extensions can exist, but this is the extension which has been the most useful for applications.

Comment: If it were a function, What would it be useful for, and if there are no known uses, how would I adjust it to keep it unique from other preexisting functions if possible? Not that I don't enjoy those functions as they are quite useful and versatile as they are. Thanks for pointing these out!

Comment: "*What would it be useful for*"  You seem to misunderstand the nature of mathematics.  Typically the uses are found *before* the functions.  It is the usefulness that inspires the definitions... not the other way around.  Things are defined in a way to solve the problems that we want solved.  I don't expect there to be much if any use to your extension.

Comment: I see. I haven't experienced that, however, I have seen it everywhere else. My luck, however, isn't on that side, however. So I'm just exploring ideas. Thank you for your information.